# Reading huge JSON array to get specific item

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, file, stream

I have a huge `JSON` file where the top level structure is an array, and it basically contains many subarrays like this: `[ [], [], [], ... [] ]`

- Each subarray is actually quite small so it is loadable in memory;
  the sheer size of the file comes from the number of subarrays.
- Suppose I already know the index of the subarray I want to access
  beforehand;
- how can I get just that subarray without having to load the entire
  JSON file into memory?
- What's the least convoluted way to achieve this?

Comment: if it's strictly a two dimensional array, and no data has `[` character in it, then you could read the file until the correct number of `[` have been read, and then read until the `]` and parse the block between

Comment: and even if it's not a 2-dimensional array, you can still do it. Just count the depth level and take into account if you are being inside a "string" where [ ] and \" also may occur. It's hard to do w/o automated tests. But if you set up the tests, then just think about some test cases, do the implementation. Later if you find a bug — add a test, make it work. And you'll know that nothing else was broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use any 3rd party JSON streaming parsers like

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json

A comprehensive list is here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7543#issuecomment-41970902